# How to get some store information in my Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, stores

I got the following two statements for my dutch store (Magento 1.9.3.4), with the following issues:

```
<?php $_BaseUrl=Mage::app()->getStore()->getHomeUrl() ; ?>
```

With this statement I am getting the home page plus '/nl', but I just need it without the 'nl'. Example: I get www.homepage.com/nl instead of www.homepage.com

```
<?php $countryId=Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode(); ?>
```

With this second statement, I get 'Netherlands' instead of 'nl'

Could you guys help me to achieve what I want? PHP version is 5.6.31

Thanks for your collaborations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php $_BaseUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getHomeUrl(); ?>` = **www.homepage.com/nl**

`<?php $_BaseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>` =  **www.homepage.com/**

Happy coding :)

Comment: This worked out :) now trying to figure out how to get 'nl' instead of 'Netherlands' or 'nl_NL'

Comment: `<?php $_codeStore = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() ?>` OR
`<?php $_languageStore = Mage::app()->getStore()->getLanguageCode() ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing your looking to get the locale for this result or you could just do a preg_replace

```
// Gets the current store's details
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

// Gets the current store's id
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

// Gets the current store's code
$storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();

// Gets the current website's id
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

// Gets the current store's group id
$storeGroupId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getGroupId();

// Gets the current store's name
$storeName = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();

// Gets the current store's sort order
$storeSortOrder = Mage::app()->getStore()->getSortOrder();

// Gets the current store's status
$storeIsActive = Mage::app()->getStore()->getIsActive();

// Gets the current store's locale
$storeLocaleCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getLocaleCode();

// Gets the current store's home url
$storeHomeUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getHomeUrl();
```

Comment: Hi. I tried those but It did not work. Could you provide an example on how preg_replace should work?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9.4.0 and maybe all versions in 1.x use:

Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/address');

and the following params, it depends what you want to get:

- general/store_information/name
- general/store_information/phone
- general/store_information/merchant_country
- general/store_information/address
- general/store_information/merchant_vat_number